# Three.js - Make CSS3D-rendered DIV show in full-screen

Tags: css, html, three.js, fullscreen, perspectivecamera

in my experiments with the three.js library, I managed to set up two different scenes (one canvas-rendered, one css3d-rendered) shown with the same perspective camera.

Note: I am using IE 10 (no way around this).

While the objects of the canvas-rendered scene are rotated and moved heavily, the css3d-scene consists only of a single DIV element that contains a sub-DIV containing an image. The css3d-rendered DIV should show (almost) full-screen, no matter what window size. Since working with the z axis coordinate of the DIV does not make it look bigger, scaling would work to make it bigger. But, for different window sizes, different scaling factors would deliver optimum results.

But, I found out that I can also manipulate the height and width of the original div to make the rendered object bigger or smaller. Since the image within can be manipulated as easy as the div, I would prefer this method over scaling.

But I lack the competence of calculating the correct amount of pixels for the DIV to become rendered full-screen within the scene.

Here's what I got so far...

```
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: #000000;
            margin: 0px;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .element {
            width: 1000px;
            height: 750px;
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(0,255,255,0.5);
            border: 1px solid rgba(127,255,255,0.25);
            cursor: default;
        }
        .element .profile {
            position: absolute;
            top: 2.5%;
            left: 2.5%;
            width: 95%;
            height: 95%;
            background-image:url('profile.jpg');
            background-size: 100% auto;
            color: rgba(127,255,255,0.75);
        }
    </style>
...

            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 3000 );
            camera.position.z = 1000;

 ... initialize a lot of particles (that work just fine in their scene with the camera setting above)
            renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
            renderer.setClearColor(0x000000, 1);
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

  ...

// now: create the css rendered scene, create and configure DIV, add the DIV to scene

            var element = document.createElement( 'div' );
            element.className = 'element';
            element.style.width = window.innerWidth + 'px';
            element.style.height = window.innerHeight + 'px';
            element.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(0,127,127,' + ( Math.random() * 0.5 + 0.25 ) + ')';
            var profile = document.createElement( 'div' );
            profile.className = 'profile';
            profile.textContent = "";

            if (imgArray != undefined) {
                if (imgArray.length > 0) {
                profile.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + imgNameArray[0] +  ')';
                profile.style.backgroundSize = "100% auto";
                }
            }

            element.appendChild( profile );
            myimgdiv = new THREE.CSS3DObject( element );
            myimgdiv.position.x = 0;
            myimgdiv.position.y = 0;
            myimgdiv.position.z = 0;
            scene2.add( myimgdiv );

            renderer2 = new THREE.CSS3DRenderer();
            renderer2.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            renderer2.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
            renderer2.domElement.style.top = 0;

   ...

        function animate() {
            requestAnimationFrame( animate );
            render();
        }
        function render() {
            TWEEN.update();
            camera.lookAt( scene.position );
            renderer.render( scene, camera );
            renderer2.render( scene2, camera );
        }
```

Can please somebody help me to calculate the correct width and height values of "element" to make it look full-screen in the above setting?

Thank you very much in advance,

Oliver

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set the positions to the top of the screen ?
x_pos = 0;
y_pos = 0;

Comment: By now, I've done it by guessing the width, manually setting up different screen sizes, found the values for each of these settings, then calculating the sreen aspect ratio and height settings accordingly. Not very nice, I know... :)